# How to migrate mysqli to pdo

Tags: mysqli

Hi I was wondering how I would migrate a mysqli php file to use PDO. Would anyone be able to take a look at my code and see if I'm on the right track?

This is my original (mysqli) code:

```
<?php
    // connecting to database
    $conn = new mysqli('xxxxxx', 'xxxxxx', 'password', 'xxxxxx');

    $match_email = 'email';
    $match_passhash = 'passhash';

    if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
        $clean_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
        $match_email = $clean_email;
    }

    if (isset($_POST['passhash'])) {
        $clean_passhash = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['passhash']);
        $match_passhash = sha1($clean_passhash);
    }

    $userquery = "SELECT email, passhash, userlevel, confirmed, blocked FROM useraccounts
                  WHERE email = '$match_email' AND passhash = '$match_passhash'
                  AND userlevel='user' AND confirmed='true' AND blocked='false';";

    $userresult = $conn->query($userquery);
    if ($userresult->num_rows == 1) {
        $_SESSION['authorisation'] = 'knownuser';
        header("Location: userhome.php");
        exit;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['authorisation'] = 'unknownuser';
        header("Location: userlogin.php");
        exit;
    }
?>
```

And this is my attempt to migrate it to PDO:

```
<?php
    // connecting to database
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=xxxxxx; dbname=xxxxxx", "xxxxxx", "password");

    $match_email = 'email';
    $match_passhash = 'passhash';

    if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
        $clean_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
        $match_email = $clean_email;
    }

    if (isset($_POST['passhash'])) {
        $clean_passhash = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['passhash']);
        $match_passhash = sha1($clean_passhash);
    }

    $userquery = "SELECT email, passhash, userlevel, confirmed, blocked FROM useraccounts
                  WHERE email = ':match_email' AND passhash = ':match_passhash' AND
                  userlevel='user' AND confirmed='true' AND blocked='false';";

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(":match_email", $match_email);
$stmt->bindParam(":match_passhash", $match_passhash);
$stmt->execute();

    $userresult = $conn->query($userquery);
    if ($userresult->num_rows == 1) {
        $_SESSION['authorisation'] = 'knownuser';
        header("Location: userhome.php");
        exit;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['authorisation'] = 'unknownuser';
        header("Location: userlogin.php");
        exit;
    }
?>
```

I'm also not sure how to count the number of rows returned in PDO.

If anyone would be able to help me out that wold be very great.

A million thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When using [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and `$stmt->bindValue()` or `$stmt->bindParam()` you do not need to escape values with `mysqli_real_escape_string()`, PDO will do that for you.

Just remember to set a correct data type for the value. That is the third argument in the bind functions and it is a string by default so your code here is fine. I would only use `bindValue()` instead of `bindParam()` as you do not need references.

`$stmt->execute()` will run your prepared statement as a query. The other `$conn->query()` does not work with prepared statements. It is for raw queries, like you used to have with MySQLi.

When `$stmt->execute()` runs your response is saved in the `$stmt` object. For row count use `$stmt->rowCount()`.

Comment: so would I use ($stmt->rowCount() == 1) as the condition in the if statement? I tried that and there were no errors, but it didn't work the was it was supposed to (I was supposed to be able to login to the site).

Comment: Yes, and you also remove the line with `$conn->query()`. Well, was it working before with the old code?